# How to shorten this? Is there a way?

Tags: c

I have to output each test score, 5 per line and the last being the three. Is there a way to do this any shorter, as in less code?

```
int arrayDisplay(int testScore[], int size){

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", testScore[0], testScore[1], testScore[2], testScore[3], testScore[4]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", testScore[5], testScore[6], testScore[7], testScore[8], testScore[9]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", testScore[10], testScore[11], testScore[12], testScore[13], testScore[14]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", testScore[15], testScore[16], testScore[17], testScore[18], testScore[19]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", testScore[20], testScore[21], testScore[22], testScore[23], testScore[23]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d", testScore[24], testScore[25], testScore[26], testScore[27], testScore[28]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d", testScore[29], testScore[30], testScore[31]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int*t=testScore;` then `printf("%d %d %d %d %d",t[0],t[1],...`. Shorter already! Other than that, what have you tried? For instance, have you opened your text book on the page about loops?

Comment: Average of 5 question is -2 and none accepted after 7 months.  Suggest reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little dirty doing this, but:

```
    int arrayDisplay(int *testScore, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
          printf("%d ", testScore[i]);
          if (i%5==0)
          {
            printf("\n");
          }

        }

    return 0;

    }
```

To be clear: SO doesn't usually take kindly to these types of questions. Consider this your one free one ;)

Comment: You are encouraging OP's laziness by answering such questions. Do you want SO to be filled with such questions?

Comment: Edited answer, this is their first one!

Comment: Please don't help no effort posters. Also, your code doesn't reproduce the results, even if we assume that `size` is 32.

Comment: Don't forget to add `if (i % 5 != 0) putchar('\n');` after the loop, and define outside the loop too, so that the incomplete last line has a newline at the end.  There are ways to avoid the trailing blank on the line too; personally, I use them because trailing blanks are anathema to me.

Comment: thanks for the help and the advice guys. having difficulty understating pointers. What exactly does the *testsScore mean. Does that point to the array itself???

Comment: It points to the first element of the array. Note that the "array" is nothing but a block of contiguous memory, and the pointer points to the first element of it

Comment: and what do you mean SO. Did I do something wrong?? New to the community!

Comment: SO = stackoverflow, I personally don't think that what you did is "wrong" per se, but there are many questions (almost exactly) like yours and what you're asking about is introductory stuff that almost any beginner resource on C would cover. Unfortunately that's just the way the community is